# setup Chromium OS package manager?

Tags: google-chrome-os, portage

Using bash under root I tried to install some packages and whenever I tried I got

```
!!! Invalid PORTDIR_OVERLAY (not a dir): '/usr/portage'
!!! main-repo not set in DEFAULT and PORTDIR is empty. 
!!! Problem with sandbox binary. Disabling...
```

How do I install something like imagemagick, ffmpeg, gimp, vlc, etc for Chromium OS?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old but It requires a simple answer. Install homebrew
https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
Homebrew is a package manager for linux systems with no package manager (example- Chrome os, mac os)

Note: You do not use root to use homebrew. It will not work. (as said on the homebrew website)